# How to get a tomcat project path from different project in same tomcat by using java

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using this code to read a file in a tomcat project, called Project1 and now I want to get this path in different tomcat project, called Project2, using java.

```
getServlet().getServletConfig().getServletContext()
           .getResourceAsStream("pdf/invoice.jasper");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

- mark the context as [`crossContext=true`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes) in `META-INF/context.xml`
- use `getServletContext().getContext("/otherApp")` to get an instance to the other app's `SetvletContext